# Accessing Polymer element CSS properties - paper-input

Tags: html, css, polymer

Is there a method with CSS in which to set the CSS for `paper-input` such that the label is hidden?

I am wanting to remove the empty space where the label would appear.

Developer tools shows the following property for the area...

```
<vaadin-grid-column>
    <template class="header">
        <div class="horizontal layout cell">
              <label for="keyFilter" class="cell">Key</label>
              <vaadin-grid-filter class="cell" id="keyFilter" path="key" value="[[_filterKey]]">
                    <paper-input style="" slot="filter" placeholder="Search" value="{{_filterKey::input}}" focus-target></paper-input>
                </vaadin-grid-filter>
        </div>
      </template>
      <template class="cell">[[item.key]]</template>
</vaadin-grid-column>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `css` to do that. Just add `no-label-float` inside `paper-input` element.

For example:

```
<paper-input no-label-float placeholder="Search"></paper-input>
```